# Php: Exceptions: whatsit? (i.e.: when to use it and when not to...)

Tags: php, exception

My question is about the correct usage of Php `Exceptions`.

My Php app is an API server.
My code base is quite articulated, to a depth of 5-6 levels of nested calls.
Of course exceptions are a very handy way to handle an error, 
since you don't have to handle all error conditions on every level of your function calls...

To better explain what I mean, I make an exaple below.

This is a simplified excerpt from my top level code (the "router"):

```
...

$this->app->get("/persons/get", function() {
  try {
    $persons = new PersonsController($this);
    $this->success($persons->get());
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->error($e);
  });
};

...

private function error($error) {
  $response = $this->app->response();
  $response->body(json_encode([
    "error" => [
      "message" => $error->getMessage(),
  ]));
}
```

And this is a simplified excerpt from my bottom level code (the "db"):

```
...

public function get($table) {
  try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM '$table'";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new Exception("Error getting persons: ", 0, $e);
  }
}
```

I think this is a typical and effective example of useful exception handling: on a fatal error in the bottom level of the code base, the error automatically pops up to the main error handling function. The real advantage here is I don't have to mess up with handling the error condition all along the chain of functions code, from the router level through the db level...

But, what if I should use Exceptions more extensively, in the middle of my functions stack... For example:

```
class PersonsController {
  ...

  public function sync() {
    if (!mkdir($d, 0777)) {
      throw new Exception("Can't create folder $d");
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Instead of, for example:

```
class PersonsController {
  ...

  public function sync() {
    if (!mkdir($d, 0777)) {dir: DEBUG ONLY!
      return -1; # this error code will have to be handled upper in the stack...
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

The question is: ***How extensive can be the use of `Exceptions` in a Php non-trivial project?***

Comment: There are no limits in the use of exceptions. I would throw an exception in `sync()`

Comment: Nesting depth is usually a good enough reason to prefer and use exceptions extensively. Otherwise this is somewhat of a peference/opinion question. (Exception are mostly for near-fatal issues, best if there's even a remote feasibility to use them for recoverability, but shouldn't be misused for plain signaling, or development-time assertions.)